# remove multiple layers of lists in a list without using library

Tags: python, list, for-loop, recursion

I want to make a function that removes any layers of lists in a list

Example

`[[[[(1,2)]]],[[(3,4)]]] --> [(1,2),(3,4)]`

`[(1, 2), [(1, 2)]] -->[(1,2),(1,2)]`

Here is my attempt using recursion which didnt work on the second example.

```
def nolistlist(t): 
    flat_list = []
    for i in t:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            for x in t:   
                if type(x) == list:
                    for y in x:
                        flat_list.append(y)
                else:
                    flat_list.append(x)
            return nolistlist(flat_list)
        else:
            return t
```

Anyone that has a simple solution **without importing any library**? I know the problem but cant come up with a solution. Have been trying to solve this problem for while now. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could use recursion if you don't know how many layers the list you're given will be.

Comment: `numpy.flatten` can do it, but of course that violates your "no library" rule.

Comment: A oneliner: `[*eval(str(t).replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))]`

Answer (score 3):

Another version, without using global variable:

```
l = [(1, 2), [(1, 2)]]


def flatten(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for v in l:
            yield from flatten(v)
    else:
        yield l

print(list(flatten(l)))
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Better.  I just didn't see it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yours is more efficient for deeply nested lists, though.

Comment: Dumb question, never seen ``yield`` before. How do i return the result? Tried ``return list(flatten(v))`` but it didnt work..

Comment: `yield` returns a result, AND lets the function continue on to return more results.  It's a generator.  You don't need a return.  The code works as is.

Answer (score 1):

I hate this answer because it relies on a global, but I haven't figured out how to solve it with nested yields yet.

```
x = [[[[(1,2)]]],[[(3,4)]]] #--> [(1,2),(3,4)]

glist = []
def notlist(z):
    for i in z:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            notlist(i)
        else:
            glist.append(i)
    return glist

print( notlist(x) )
```

Comment: for some reason my program takes alot more time when i use global...